# Vue - instance data is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a menu of topics (e.g. "About us", "Support") and I want to be able to tell what topic is active right now. When a topic is clicked it will become the active one. Think of it as a substitute for a router that will set an active route. This is not possible in my case since I'm working in SharePoint 2010... in a content editor. So I made the decision to have an **activeTopic** variable in my Vue instance.

**The Vue instance**

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        activeTopic: '',
    }
});
```

This is because the **activeTopic** has to update another component and show some data based on the active topic. Like a router showing a child route.

**The topic component**

```
Vue.component('topic', {
    props: ["title"],
    methods: {
        setActiveTopic: function (title) {
            activeTopic = title;
        },
        isActiveTopic: function (title) {
            return activeTopic == title;
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div v-bind:class="{active: isActiveTopic(title)}" v-on:click="setActiveTopic(title)">
            <p v-text="title"></p>
        </div>
    `
});
```

The **setActiveTopic** function works as it should when I click it; it updates the activeTopic. But the **isActiveTopic** function gives me this error:

```
Error in render: "ReferenceError: activeTopic is not defined"
```

What I don't understand is that I can edit the activeTopic variable but I can't make a comparison? I've tried setting a default value but it still says it is undefined.

Comment: vue is throwing the right error. ` activeTopic` is not defined anywhere for you to assign it. It should be defined and pass as a prop to your component

Answer (score 4):

`activeTopic` should be assigned to the Vue component by setting and reading `this.activeTopic`.  As is, you have two independent `activeTopic` variables scoped within each of your component methods.

You'll also want to include `activeTopic` in the component's data block, rather than on the Vue object itself, since it's specific to the component.

(If there's a reason to put that variable on the Vue object you would either want to pass it down to the component as a `prop`, or else access it directly as `Vue.activeTopic` instead of `this.activeTopic`. I'm honestly not certain whether Vue would treat that last structure as a reactive value within components -- I've never had a reason to try that, and can't think of a situation where that'd be a reasonable architecture.)

```
Vue.component('topic', {
    props: ["title"],
    data() { return {
      activeTopic: ''
    }},
    methods: {
        setActiveTopic(title) {
            this.activeTopic = title;
        },
        isActiveTopic(title) {
            return this.activeTopic == title;
        }
    },
    template: `
        <div v-bind:class="{active: isActiveTopic(title)}" v-on:click="setActiveTopic(title)">
            <p v-text="title"></p>
        </div>
    `
});
```

Comment: but not in inside the component. It should either be defined as in this answer, or passed down to the component as a  prop. Op is only `title` so the component knows nothing about the `activeTopic`

Comment: I can now apply the active class to each topic, but having the activeTopic in the component data makes it individual and eliminates the Vue instance scenario. Passing it by props doesn't update the component if changes are made, as far as I remember. But thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: "Passing it by props doesn't update the component if changes are made" Components do need to `watch` their props for changes, yeah.

Answer (score 4):

I am new to Vue, and have seen data being defined as an object in several examples.

But apparently, as per the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function), you have to use data as a function that returns an object.

This is to ensure that all instances will have it's own version of the data object, and is not shared with all instances.

Instead of

```
data: {
  count: 0
}
```

use

```
data: function () {
  return {
    count: 0
  }
}
```

However I still don't know why in one of my component, data as an object worked, and in a child component with it's own data as an object, I got the error `count is undefined`;

I am assuming, the root element, (defined by new Vue({}) has to be a singleton, and is not intended to have several instances.

And since components, can have instances, the data in that needs to be defined as a function.